# Há jeito de inserir em tempo de execução eventos no elemento html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Imagine uma página com um único `input` de texto, ou seja, um campo de texto no documento HTML assim: `<input value="digite aqui" type="text" id="el"/>`.

Mas quero inserir neste campo de texto, através de Javascript, os *eventos* `onBlur()` e `onFocus()`.

O código final seria

```
<input value="digite aqui" type="text"
    onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'digite aqui';}" 
    onfocus="if(this.value == 'digite aqui') {this.value = '';}"
    />
```

Este `script` acima é um exemplo de como desejo que fique, contém partes dos *eventos* que gostaria de fazer a inclusão no momento que clicar em um botão.

Queria incluir partes, dentro de um `input` já existente na página, nada de criar este código dinamicamente.

Portanto pegar o `onblur="if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'digite aqui';}"`, juntamente com `onfocus="if(this.value == 'digite aqui') {this.value = '';}"` e jogar no `<input value="digite aqui" type="text" id="el"/>`

Ok, alguém propõe uma idéia de como fazer esta manobra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var accoes = {
    onblur: "if(this.value == '') {this.value = 'digite aqui';}",
    onfocus: "if(this.value == 'digite aqui') {this.value = '';}"
}
for (var prop in accoes) {
    input.setAttribute(prop, accoes[prop]);
}
```

#### Exepmlo: https://jsfiddle.net/8c6j46Lg/

A parte importante é o [`.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) que basicamente muda o HTML como se lá estivesse de inicio. Para fazer a funcionalidade mais organizada criei um objeto para guardar essas regras.